# Referential Integrity & Tuning: Replacing Complex Natural Keys with Surrogate Keys & Indices in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, referential-integrity

I have been tasked to improve performance in a staging database I originally created, in particular for deletion of data.

I originally created the tables using (basically) the natural keys of the data source from which the data is being pulled. As a result, the keys are multi-part and quite complex.

To speed things up, I created surrogate primary and foreign keys and wrote a function to populate them so that joins would be much simpler. I also created keys to the root of the hierarchy in an attempt to speed up deletion of an entire "batch".

However, just populating the surrogate foreign keys is proving highly inefficient, and I'm at a loss as to why or what to do about it.

For each table, I followed this pattern:

1. Drop existing composite primary keys and foreign keys.
2. If the table has children (or in some cases, self-references), add a new id column of type SERIAL and designate it as the new primary key.
3. Create a unique index named ux_ that covers all fields of the former composite primary key.
4. If the table has parents and/or self-references, add a field or fields named _id of type INTEGER.
5. Add foreign keys named fk_ that link the new integer fields to the id fields of the parent table.
6. Create indices on the foreign key fields in the child table.
7. Create indices on the fields in the child table that would originally have constituted the natural foreign key.
8. Add a foreign key to the root of the hierarchy with delete cascade.
9. Add an index on the foreign key to the root of the hierarchy.

The result is probably too complex, but please bear with me.

Here's an example of a leaf table:

```
CREATE TABLE staging.cost_years
(
    batch timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    request_packet_sent_timestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    request integer NOT NULL,
    program character varying(256) NOT NULL,
    estimate_type character varying(10) NOT NULL,
    effective_date date NOT NULL,
    subprogram character varying(256) NOT NULL,
    referenced_estimate character varying(25) NOT NULL,
    symbol character varying(14),
    fiscal_year character(4) NOT NULL,
    <unimportant_stuff>
    cost_subprograms_id integer,
    cost_accounts_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT fk_cost_accounts_cost_subprograms FOREIGN KEY (cost_subprograms_id)
        REFERENCES staging.cost_subprograms (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fk_cost_years_batch FOREIGN KEY (batch)
        REFERENCES staging.batch (batch) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_cost_years_cost_accounts FOREIGN KEY (cost_accounts_id)
        REFERENCES staging.cost_accounts (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

-- Index: fkix_cost_years_batch

CREATE INDEX fkix_cost_years_batch
    ON staging.cost_years USING btree
    (batch)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: fkix_cost_years_cost_accounts

CREATE INDEX fkix_cost_years_cost_accounts
    ON staging.cost_years USING btree
    (cost_accounts_id)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: fkix_cost_years_cost_subprograms

CREATE INDEX fkix_cost_years_cost_subprograms
    ON staging.cost_years USING btree
    (cost_subprograms_id)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: ix_cost_years_cost_accounts

CREATE INDEX ix_cost_years_cost_accounts
    ON staging.cost_years USING btree
    (batch, request_packet_sent_timestamp, request, program, estimate_type,
     effective_date, subprogram, referenced_estimate, symbol)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: ix_cost_years_cost_subprograms

CREATE INDEX ix_cost_years_cost_subprograms
    ON staging.cost_years USING btree
    (batch, request_packet_sent_timestamp, request, program, estimate_type,
     effective_date, subprogram, referenced_estimate)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Index: ux_cost_years

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_cost_years
    ON staging.cost_years USING btree
    (batch, request_packet_sent_timestamp, request, program, estimate_type,
    effective_date, subprogram, referenced_estimate, symbol, fiscal_year)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

One of the queries I'm using to try to populate the surrogate keys is:

```
-- cost_years to cost_subprograms
UPDATE
    staging.cost_years
SET
    cost_subprograms_id = cost_subprograms.id
FROM
    staging.cost_subprograms
WHERE
    cost_years.batch = staging.cost_subprograms.batch
    AND cost_years.request_packet_sent_timestamp = staging.cost_subprograms.request_packet_sent_timestamp
    AND cost_years.request = staging.cost_subprograms.request
    AND cost_years.program = staging.cost_subprograms.program
    AND cost_years.estimate_type = staging.cost_subprograms.estimate_type
    AND cost_years.effective_date = staging.cost_subprograms.effective_date
    AND cost_years.subprogram = staging.cost_subprograms.subprogram
    AND cost_years.referenced_estimate = staging.cost_subprograms.referenced_estimate
    AND cost_years.batch = COALESCE(batch_in, cost_years.batch);
```

It takes forever, and when I run EXPLAIN on it, it's ignoring the index (ix_cost_years_cost_subprograms) I added specifically for this purpose and doing a nested loop:

```
'[
  {
    "Execution Time": 321003.489,
    "Planning Time": 2.452,
    "Plan": {
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Filter": "(batch = batch)",
              "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
              "Relation Name": "cost_years",
              "Alias": "cost_years",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Actual Rows": 1567083,
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Rows Removed by Filter": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1
            },
            {
              "Scan Direction": "Forward",
              "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
              "Node Type": "Index Scan",
              "Index Cond": "(
    (batch = cost_years.batch) AND
    (request_packet_sent_timestamp = cost_years.request_packet_sent_timestamp) AND
    (request = cost_years.request) AND
    ((program)::text = (cost_years.program)::text) AND
    ((estimate_type)::text = (cost_years.estimate_type)::text) AND
    (effective_date = cost_years.effective_date) AND
    ((subprogram)::text = (cost_years.subprogram)::text) AND 
    ((referenced_estimate)::text = (cost_years.referenced_estimate)::text))",
              "Relation Name": "cost_subprograms",
              "Alias": "cost_subprograms",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Actual Rows": 1,
              "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
              "Actual Loops": 1567083,
              "Index Name": "ux_cost_subprograms"
            }
          ],
          "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
          "Join Type": "Inner",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Actual Rows": 1567083,
          "Parent Relationship": "Member",
          "Actual Loops": 1
        }
      ],
      "Node Type": "ModifyTable",
      "Relation Name": "cost_years",
      "Alias": "cost_years",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Actual Rows": 0,
      "Operation": "Update",
      "Actual Loops": 1
    },
    "Triggers": []
  }
]'
```

I know it's a lot to ask, but does anyone quickly see why it's not trying to use ix_cost_years_cost_subprograms? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the sizes of indexes please

Comment: How do I determine the size of the indices? Sorry...

Comment: in `psql` `\di+ pattern`, or `select pg_catalog.pg_indexes_size('name_here')`

Comment: staging.fkix_cost_years_batch: 492MB
staging.fkix_cost_years_cost_accounts: 267MB;
staging.fkix_cost_years_cost_subprograms: 226MB;
staging.ix_cost_years_cost_accounts: 1694MB;
staging.ix_cost_years_cost_subprograms: 2302MB;
staging.ux_cost_years: 932MB

Comment: Total for all indices for the table is 6198804480 (from select pg_catalog.pg_indexes_size('staging.cost_years'))